# Reading BLOB file from mySQL with Python

Tags: python, mysql, file, blob

First of all, I'm new to Database Applications. I'm trying to receive a BLOB file from mySQL database; currently trying to run a python code block that I found from a website. I was able to load the BLOB file to the database successfully, however I'm failing to receive the BLOB file that I uploaded. Here is the python code.

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
from mysql.connector import errorcode

def write_file(data, filename):
    # Convert binary data to proper format and write it on Hard Disk
        with open(filename, 'wb') as file:
            file.write(data)
def readBLOB(emp_id, photo):
        print("Reading BLOB data from python_employee table")
        try:
            connection = mysql.connector.connect(user='***', password='***',
                          host='******',
                          database='*****')
            cursor = connection.cursor(prepared=True)
            sql_fetch_blob_query = """SELECT * from faceimages where id = %s"""
            cursor.execute(sql_fetch_blob_query, (emp_id, ))
            record = cursor.fetchall()
            for row in record:
                print("Id = ", row[0] )
                print("Name = ", row[1])
                image =  row[2]
                print("Storing employee image and bio-data on disk \n")
                write_file(image, photo)
               #write_file(file, bioData)
        except mysql.connector.Error as error :
            connection.rollback()
            print("Failed to read BLOB data from MySQL table {}".format(error))
        finally:
            #closing database connection.
            if(connection.is_connected()):
                cursor.close()
                connection.close()
                print("MySQL connection is closed")
readBLOB(1, '/home/can/Desktop/photo.jpg')
```

The expected result should be :

```
Reading BLOB data from python_employee table
Id = 1
Name = Eric
Storing employee image and bio-data on disk
MySQL connection is closed
```

My result is as follows :

```
Reading BLOB data from python_employee table
Id =  1
Name =  bytearray(b'Eric')
Storing employee image and bio-data on disk     
MySQL connection is closed
```

The code creates a .jpg file but the file can not be loaded.

> "Could not load image “photo.jpg”."
>   "Error interpreting JPEG image file (Improper call to JPEG library in state 201)"

Comment: How big is the JPEG image file? What is the ondisk size of the witten file? The MySQL variable [max_allowed_packet](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) needs to be set larger than this. There's no drawback to having this set its maximium value.

Comment: @danblackit is 200ish KB.

Comment: @CanÖzgen "ish" isn't really helpful. What are the exact sizes of file that you store and retrieve? Are those sizes exactly the same?

Comment: I just checked it, the one that I upload is 343KB, the one that I retrieve is 1 byte somehow.